# Cylinder Volume: replacing cylinder with radius r with n cylinders with radius (r/n)

Tags: calculus, geometry

This is a selfimposed question I came up with recently, which I wasn't able to solve yet, probably because I am going about it the wrong way

**Question**:**I have heard that replacing  a cylinder with smaller ones leads to an increase in surface area and want to check this assumption.** Suppose you have a normal cylinder given with radius $r$ and height $h$, how does the surface area change if you replace the cylinder with n-cylinders with radius $\frac{r}{n}$ (while keeping the height the same)

My attempt so far: The surface of the normal cylinder $O_{1}=2\pi h + 2\pi r^2 = 2\pi r (h+r)$
and the surface of the smaller cylinders would be : $O_{n}=n2\pi \frac{r}{n}(h+\frac{r}{n}) = 2\pi r (h+\frac{r}{n})$

so for $n \to \infty $ the total surface of the smaller cylinders would end up being $2\pi r h$

This doesn't seem correct on the first glance... but where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mistake.  The lateral surface area of the cylinder is not changed by the replacement because it is multiplied by a factor $\frac 1n$ for the radius and by a factor $n$ for the number of cylinders.  The area of the ends is multiplied by $\frac 1{n^2}$ for the radius and $n$ for the number of cylinders, so goes to zero.

Comment: So why then is it claimed that replacing a bigger tube with smaller ones increases their surface volume?

Comment: The volume of the cylinders is also multiplied by $\frac 1n$, so the lateral surface to volume ratio increases by a factor of $n$

Comment: Aha, so replacing them ends up giving the biggest surface for the smallest volume, and not necessarily the biggest surface.